# Override Bootstrap CSS in Yii2

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I have a `NavBar` and I want to override all the classes that Yii is putting on that widget. After searching inn Google and reading the docs, I found that this code:

```
Yii::$container->set('yii\bootstrap\NavBar', [
    'containerOptions' => [
        'class' => ''
    ]
]);

NavBar::begin([
    'containerOptions' => [
        'class' => 'no-horizontal-padding navbar-content'
    ]
]);
```

is supposed to override (delete, actually) all classes in the `container` of my `NavBar`, but this is not the case. I keep seeing my 2 classes and the default `NavBar` classes.

How can I remove those classes and keep only mine?

Please refrain any hacky solutions like removing the classes with JS on the client side. I'm looking for a proper way of doing this.

EDIT:

I'm adding the generated HTML as requested:

```
<nav id="w0" class="navbar-inverse navbar" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid no-horizontal-padding">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#w0-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="w0-collapse" class="no-horizontal-padding navbar-content collapse navbar-collapse">
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: could you add the html that is generated by the widget with the above code?

Comment: @deacs Sure, give me a moment

Comment: thanks! so it's about this line: `<div id="w0-collapse" class="no-horizontal-padding navbar-content collapse navbar-collapse"></div>` right? ie, which classes do u want removed/overridden?

Comment: @deacs Yes, that is correct. I want to remove the `collapse navbar-collapse ` classes.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove `collapse` and `navbar-collapse` out of the box, using the widget parameters, you can't.

As you can see in the code for the [NavBar component in Yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/blob/master/NavBar.php#L124), those classes are hard-coded in there.

Your options:

- Modify the Navbar.php file and remove this classes (not recommended).
- Write directly in HTML your navbar (not ideal, but is a valid workaround).
- Create your own custom Navbar Component for Yii2 (recommended, because you can copy the Navbar.php file, remove those classes and change the namespace).

[Here is a simple tutorial for creating your components and using them.](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/747/write-use-a-custom-component-in-yii2-0/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `collapse` and `navbar-collapse` out of the box, using the widget parameters, try this:

add to your NavBar...

```
'collapseOptions' => [
    'class' => [
        'collapse' => '',
        'widget' => '',
    ]
]
```

will keep like this...

```php
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => Yii::$app->name,
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
     'collapseOptions' => [
        'class' => [
            'new' => 'navbar-nav-scroll',
            'collapse' => '',
            'widget' => '',
        ],
    ],
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top',
    ],
]);
```

it works for me.